# Decoupled authentication flow, very vulnerable to Man in the Middle attacks?

Tags: tls, authentication, man-in-the-middle

I'm in the process of building a kinda odd mechanism to "bypass" authentication. Which of course I know its weird, but many business requirements are weird... So it is a design that derives from business decisions that state that user authentication is an impediment, also the code on the client's backed must not be intrusive.

To explain. I have a **web application** and a **ClientWebApp** which has an SDK I've made that exposes an API so he can easily use it in his code and interact with that **web application**. The **ClientWebApp** is someone else's application that wants to consume some of the information my **web application** can create.

The **ClientWebApp** is using HTTPS POST to call my **web application** including some user data that my **web application** needs in order to work. This communication happens with a client_credentials OAuth token... So far so good. The **web application** is storing all this information in its database and it generates a unique URL with a dynamic segment (`UUID`) which `UUID` corresponds to the key of the database entry of the incoming information from the **ClientWebApp**. As a last steps it returns it as a response to the POST request back to **ClientWebApp**.

Now the **ClientWebApp** is redirecting the user to that unique URL (which is actually my **web application**) and if the **web application** can find an unused `UUID` that matches with the `UUID` in the URL path it lets the user browse. Right after the match, the `UUID` gets invalidated so that the user is not able to refresh (or the `UUID` to be used again).

So my **web application** has no authentication (has only HTTPS) but only responds to "non-guessable" URLs that have been passed via HTTPS POST to the oauth authenticated machine.

Now I'm thinking of a scenario where a malicious person goes to a cafe or something and opens up a public wi-fi and starts sniffing the traffic, and a "dumb" end-user in the same cafe logs in automatically and starts using it as his wi-fi.

Will the malicious person be able to set a rule or something that will cut the connection when my URL comes through, intercept that URL and use it to impersonate the end-user and see their data?

I kind of feel that the answer is an absolute yes but at the same time, I'm not quite sure...

Thank you!

PS: There are many ways of tackling this otherwise but in this example I can't create a public endpoint on **ClientWebApp**'s server that I can check something with him, also authentication is out of the question when the user enters the page. Though all of that happen inside a very secure **ClientWebApp** (so the user has logged properly)..

I will also add a sequence diagram showing how these components interact (the vulnerable step should be if the MitM sits at step 10 between the EndUser and the WebApplication)

[image]